# MathJax event just before a latex expression is typset

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I have a MathJax sample at [Demo sample](https://js.do/sun21170/66209), which works as expected. All it does is typset the latex expressions within a div having an id of mathDiv.

I need to execute some custom logic when the third latex expression is about to be typset i.e. when `${  x  } ^ {  4  } = 81 $ if $ x^4 - 9 =0 $` is going to be typset.

**Question**

Can I execute some custom JavaScript just before the above latex expression get typset by MathJax and if yes, then how would I do it?

I was thinking there might be some event model associated with MathJax typesetting, but couldn't find any in the docs.

The same demo sample code is as below.

```
 <h2>Math Test</h2>
 <div id="mathDiv">1. Solve for x $$X^2-1 = 8$$. 
     <br>2. Evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow b}{  (x-10)  }$$
     <br>3. Is ${  x  } ^ {  4  } = 81 $ if $ x^4 - 9 =0 $ ?
 </div>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "mathDiv"]);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what code you want to run before the expression is typeset?

Comment: @DavideCervone, I have a situation where a user types latex into a text area. Before rendering the typed latex, I want to wrap each latex expression into its own span element. For example, the first latex expression would be wrapped in `<span id='math0'></span>`, the second latex expression would be wrapped within `<span id='math1'></span>`. I need to do this wrapping to satisfy some requirement in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are signals for when math is typeset (see this [example](https://rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.5/test/sample-signals.html)), though the signals for HTML-CSS output are a bit more complicate than for the other output formats.

But there is another approach that may work better for you.  You can register a preprocessor that will run after the tex2jax preprocessor has located the math in the page, and that will put your wrapper around the math at that point.  Then when the math is typeset, it will be inside the wrapper automatically.

Here is one example for that:

```html
<style>
#math0 {color:red}
#math1 {color:blue}
#math2 {color:green; font-size: 200%}
#math3 {color:purple; font-size: 75%}
</style>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
});
MathJax.Hub.Register.PreProcessor(function (element) {
  //
  // Get the math scripts created by tex2jax
  //
  var math = element.querySelectorAll('script[type^="math/tex"]');
  //
  //  Loop through them in reverse (since this
  //  is a live list)
  //
  for (var i = math.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //
    //  Get the script and any preview that preceeds it
    //
    var script = math[i];
    var preview = script.previousSibling;
    if (preview && preview.className !== 'MathJax_Preview') preview = null;
    //
    //  Create the wrapper span and give it an id
    //  (If you will be typesetting more than once, 
    //   you will need to keep a global id number
    //   and use that rather than i)
    //
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.id = 'math'+i;
    //
    //  Insert the wrapper in place of the script
    //  and append the preview and script to
    //  the wrapper.
    //
    script.parentNode.replaceChild(span,script);
    if (preview) span.append(preview);
    span.append(script);
  }
},50);  // use priority 50 so it follows the standard MathJax preprocessors
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full"></script>

<h2>Math Test</h2>
 <div id="mathDiv">1. Solve for x $$X^2-1 = 8$$. 
     <br>2. Evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow b}{  (x-10)  }$$
     <br>3. Is ${  x  } ^ {  4  } = 81 $ if $ x^4 - 9 =0 $ ?
 </div>
```

Here, the wrappers are styled to add color, and to scale the third and fourth expressions.

I hope the comments make it clear what is happening.  This preprocessor will be run any time `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` is called, so you can use that as normal.

Note that if the math is in the page initially, as it is here, there is no need to queue the `Typeset()` call by hand (as MathJax will typeset the page initially).  If you are dynamically modifying the page, then you will need to do that.

Comment: When preprocessor is called then the latex expressions have not been typeset. Is that right? If yes, then how come the script tag with latex expression and MathJax_Preview element are there. Normally, when I typset a latex expression, then after typsetting is completed these elements can be seen in rendered html of page.

Comment: Because of the priority of 50 assigned to this preprocessor, it runs *after* the standard tex2jax preprocessor runs.  That preprocessor's job is to locate the delimited math in the page, remove it, and insert the `script` tags (and previews) that you see here.  This all happens before the math is typeset.  After the preprocessors run, then the input processor runs (converting the TeX code to an internal MathML form), and after that, the output processor runs, turning the internal MathML into HTML in the page.

Comment: I am using Latex in my editor and not MathML. I guess your explanation still applies. Can you point to any documentation on this?

Comment: Note that I indicated that the TeX code is converted to MathML internally, not that you used MathML initially.  MathJax uses MathML internally to represent your math.  The output jax "turns the **internal** MathML into HTML in the page", as I mentioned above.  See the [MathJax Processing Model](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/model.html) for details.